# Extract array key into NEW variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array where there is a key and a value. I generate it by cycling through an image folder:

```
$images = array(); 
foreach (glob("images/myimages/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,JPG}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {  
    $images[$filename] = filemtime($filename); 
}

arsort($images); 

$newest = array_slice($images, 0, 5);
```

This gives me the following array:

```
images/myimages/image1.jpg => 1472497034
images/myimages/IMG_02.JPG => 2347389498
images/myimages/DSC_0066.png => 7837392948
images/myimages/fred_bloggs.jpg => 1472497034
images/myimages/IMG4532.JPG => 2347389498
```

I want to extract each key from the $newest array into a new variable so image1.jpg becomes $var1, IMG_02.JPG becomes $var2 etc.

I have 2 problems. First, the filename needs the "images/myimages/" pathname stripping from it (and a check whether files exist in that folder). Second, I can't see how to extract the 5 keys into those 5 new variables. All the examples I see extract the key into a variable of the same name such as here http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why extract to vars?  Just use `$newest = array_keys($newest);` and then `echo $newest[0]; `etc...  Or loop thru it.  Also see `basename()`.

Comment: You almost never want variables like `$var1`, `$var2`, etc. Whenever you're doing that, you should just use an array.

Comment: As said in the previous comments, better use an array than `$varX`, but FYI, you can have a look at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.list.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver - Nice answer that simplifies what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Really I dont understand why you need that.
But you could do something like this:

```
$prefix = 'var'; $count = 0;
foreach($newest as $key => $value) {
   $count++;
   ${$prefix.$count} = $key;
}

echo $var1; // 'images/myimages/image1.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off just using an array:

```
$newest = array_keys($newest);
```

Then access 0-4:

```
echo $newest[0];
```

To get just the filename:

```
$newest = array_map('basename', $newest);
```

Or you can just use `basename()` when creating your original array.